# Build report in C#

Tags: c#, rdlc

I am C# newbie and I would like to ask for a help here: Any samples to show the C# back end code to populate records from multiple table of SQL database to rdlc report by using queries? If I need to create extra column for e.g. total quantity, do I have to specify it into sql queries?

Comment: what you have done so far??? . Just google it!!!

Comment: I have done the queries as shown:
SELECT customername, customerid, warehouseno, unit
FROM Customer 
INNER JOIN Warehouse 
ON customername BETWEEN name1 AND name2

After I done the queries, how should I populate all the relevant records to the C# report?
I have googled but too much of choice, I have insufficient of time to test it one by one so I am ask for a help here

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/robo60/StandaloneRDLCReports11142007183516PM/StandaloneRDLCReports.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I started using rdlc I found a lot of usefull info on http://gotreportviewer.com/:

I recommended reading these links before starts using rdlc:

- [data sources](http://gotreportviewer.com/definedata/index.html)
- [report parameters](http://gotreportviewer.com/localmodeparameters/index.html)
- [master detail](http://gotreportviewer.com/masterdetail/index.html)
- [subreports](http://gotreportviewer.com/subreports/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody reach this thread for help:-

go to these links to start with RDLC reports using C#

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a72401/rdlc-report-generation-using-dataset/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/robo60/StandaloneRDLCReports11142007183516PM/StandaloneRDLCReports.aspx